# “Integral” versus “essential”

Tags: difference

From Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary:

> ❍ integral : being an essential part of something
>
> ❍ essential : completely necessary; extremely important in a particular situation or for a particular activity

The definitions of them look very similar. Are there any differences between them?

Comment: The word "integral" can mean "essential" but not always. Another meaning of "integral" is "a part of". One version of some product might have an integral component installed during manufacture, which is not essential but gives added functionality.

Comment: Integral refers to a part of something, whereas essential can be anything that is necessary. A worker is integral to the working of a company, his tools are essential for his job.